# TinyInt column active maps properly to boolean in HQL but gives IllegalArgument exception when using native query

Tags: hibernate

I altered a table and added a  tinyInt column *Active*

```
@Column(name = "Active")
private boolean active;
```

that has 1/0 in Database and it maps properly to  boolean true/false in Java when used in HQL

```
Query query = sess.createQuery("FROM Message where Active = false")
 retval = query.list();
```

But If I use a native query

```
String query = "Select * from Message where ChainID IN (Select ChainID from ChainUser where UserId = :p_contactUserID  and ChainID in "
                + " (Select ChainID FROM ChainUser WHERE UserID =  :p_userID  AND Type='MESSAGE'))"; 

Dictionary<String, String> parameters = new Hashtable<String, String>();
parameters.put("p_contactUserID", Integer.toString(contactUserID));
parameters.put("p_userID", Integer.toString(userID));

Query query = sess.createSQLQuery(query ).setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(instance.getClass()));
                        
    for (String key : Collections.list(parameters.keys())) {
                        
       query.setParameter(key, parameters.get(key));            
   }            
   retval = query.list();
```

gives "IllegalArgument exception for property active ...." when using native query.

Why is it not able to do the mapping of active to boolean in the case of native query?

What I tried -

1. Adding the following for the column *Active* in my entity

```
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType")   
    @Column(columnDefinition=”TINYINT(1)”)
```

With different combinations (both together, only @Type but not columnDefinition etc..) It did not work.

2. I even tried to do a

scalar.put("Active", new Boolean);
Nor  did this  work.

**Update**: I had to do the work-around of creating a POJO without the Active column and change my native query from

```
Select * from Message where ChainID IN (Select ChainID from ChainUser where UserId = :p_contactUserID  and ChainID in "
                + " (Select ChainID FROM ChainUser WHERE UserID =  :p_userID  AND Type='MESSAGE'))";
```

to

```
Select ChainID from Message where ChainID IN (Select ChainID from ChainUser where UserId = :p_contactUserID  and ChainID in "
                + " (Select ChainID FROM ChainUser WHERE UserID =  :p_userID  AND Type='MESSAGE'))";
```

to only select the tuples ( in this case, **chainID**) I require so that the hibernate library then does not try to map the *Active* column, which it was doing if I passed the Entity to it instead of the POJO. But this work-around was hard work. Imagine if there were a few dozen native queries. I would have to change

Select * from Messages

And analyse each query to see what is being used in the business logic and add only those tuples in the query just so that it would avoid the newly altered *Active* column rendering this work-around useless and bug-prone.

Anyone has any idea? I would be grateful

Comment: Any reason for not using a HQL query?

Comment: How do you run the native query end convert the result to Messages?

Comment: @Davide I added the code, let me know if you require anything else

Comment: Perhaps `.setParameter(1, true, ShortType.INSTANCE)` would work?

Comment: @Davide reason for not using the HQL query was that at the time we were writing this query we were thinking "less hits to DB, the better" and doing it by HQL would cost 3 queries i.e 3 round-trips. Regardless, a library should not get stuck at native what it does well with entity-db mapping or at least give a work around for native without throwing IllegalArgumentExc for property setter....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are using a result transformer instead of specifying the result as an entity:

```
Query query = ormSession.createSQLQuery( query ).addEntity( Message.class );
```

Comment: this worked, thanks Davide. The hibernate docs infact mention you can use addEntity for native queries. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#d0e13696